# How does Keras.Model() retrieve the different layers between its passed input and output layers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I have recently been learning Keras and am trying to understand how the keras.Model function is able to interpolate the different layers between passed input and output layers. Do the input or output layers contain knowledge of the intermediate layers or are they stored as static data within the keras API?

The following is an example of this:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
```

Which outputs:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "functional_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 4)                 16        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 25        
=================================================================
Total params: 41
Trainable params: 41
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

But only the input and output layers (layer 0 and 2 respectively) were provided to the keras.Model() function. Where does the middle layer come from in the summary function?

Thanks for the help!